# Strang Calculus Section 1.4 Circular Motion, Question 15: Find area under v = cos (t)

Tags: calculus

I'm looking at [Gilbert Strang's calculus text](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/resources/Strang/Edited/Calculus/Calculus.pdf).

Section 1.4, question 15: Find the area under $v = \cos t$ from the change in $f = \sin t$ from $t = 0$ to $t = \pi$.

From what I understand, this should be $0$ since $\sin(\pi) - \sin(0) = 0$. But the answer key gives the answer as $2$. Please give me a sanity check, am I wrong or is the answer key wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If the area below the $x$-axis is considered to be negative, then your answer is correct.  The answer in the book would make sense if you added the absolute value of the area below the $x$-axis in the interval $[\pi/2, \pi]$ to the area between the curve and the $x$-axis in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: The "area under a curve" does not typically refer to the signed area.